# Access button from different controller (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've just started making my app in Xcode but I need to access a button on a different controller. Can I just set the controllers class as viewcontroller as well as the first one? Or do I need to create a new class and link them some how?

Comment: Do you use Stroybourd or you constuct your UI in code?
What do you want to do with that button?

Comment: I used storyboard to create the button. I have other objects so let me explain in more detail. I have a text field and a button on one controller and two text fields on the other. What I want to acomplish when the button on the first controller is clicked the second controller will show and if the text field on the first controller equals, for example "hello" the text fields on the second controller will again, for example say "hello to you too"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the object of interest from view controller A to view controller B like this:

```
// In view controller A
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueFromAToB"]) {

      NSString *myValue = [_myTextField text];
     [(BViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setMyValue:myValue];
   }
}

// In view controller B
@interface BViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myValue;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // TODO: Evaluate myValue here
}
```

Don't forget to give the segue (represented by the line connecting the two controllers) from A to B an id in storyboard (e.g. "SegueFromAToB")